# How to zoom in when a value from a drop-down is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

As the title says i want to zoom on the location selected in the drop-down list. I have different markers on the map, locations which are in the drop-down too, so when i chose one from the drop-down i want to zoom in and center on the location. I'm pretty new at this javascript, jquery thing and any help would be highly appreciated.
Here is my drop-down list:

```
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectedValue" >
            <option>--Select--</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
```

Here is how my Google Maps is rendered and populated:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        {
            center: { lat: 46.770920, lng: 23.589920 },
            zoom: 13
        });

    $.get("/Home/GetAllLocation",
        function (data, status) {
            var marker = [];
            var contentString = [];
            var infowindow = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: { lat: data[i].latitudine, lng: data[i].longitudine },
                    map: map
                });

                contentString[i] = '<div id="content">' +
                    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' +
                    data[i].name +
                    '</h1>' +
                    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                    '<p><b> Numar locuri Fast Charging: </b>' +
                    data[i].nrOfBikes +
                    '<p><b> Numar locuri care nu-s Fast Charging: </b>' +
                    data[i].nrOfAvailableBikes +
                    '<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" ><p>View Details</a>' +
                    '<form asp-action=""><div><input type="submit" value="Open" class="btn btn-success"> <input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn btn-danger"></div></form>';

                infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString[i]
                });
                var mdl = marker[i];
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i],
                    'click',
                    (function (mdl, i) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i]);
                            for (var j = 0; j < infowindow.length; j++) {
                                if (j != i) {
                                    infowindow[j].close();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    })(marker[i], i));
            }
        });

}
```

And here is what i have found on the internet and tried to apply to what i need, but i'm not sure i did it in the right way:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#selectedValue', function() {
    var latlngzoom = jQuery(this).val();
    var newzoom = 1 * latlngzoom[2];
    newlat = 1 * latlngzoom[0];
    newlng = 1 * latlngzoom[1];
    map.setZoom(newzoom);
    map.setCenter({lat:newlat, lng: newlng})
});
```

Comment: You're getting the `@item.Id` value, what is that ID? You need to use coordinates, are those coordinates?

Comment: The `Id` is the "location" id from the database, and those (latitudine and longitudine ) are coordinates also from the database.

Comment: Could you provide an example for that `@item.Id` value? Is that a string, an array, a JSON object...? Also, why are you doing `1 * latlngzoom[0];`?

Comment: `@item.Id` is an int, representing for example the id of the first city from the database. Ex: I have 17 cities in my database and each city has it's own id, from 1 to 17. I'm not sure i made it more clear now...

Comment: Ok, now I get it. That ID is not the coordinates that Google Maps needs in order to locate that city (or whatever it is) in their map, you need to provide real and valid coordinates, both `lat` and `lng` ("latitude" and "longitude"). If you don't have those coordinates in your database, you could try to use [Google Maps Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to convert the address or city to real and useful coordinates. Just to be sure, could you `console.log()` that `latlngzoom` variable and paste it here?

Comment: I already have real and valid coordinates for both "latitudine" and "logitudine", that's how my map is populated.

Comment: Then you need to get that data to use `map.setCenter({...})`, I'd suggest using `data` attributes in your HTML for both things, then use jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get those attributes in the HTML from the ID where the select was changed to.

Comment: Quick sample: https://codepen.io/jimmyadaro/pen/YbXeLV?editors=1010

Comment: I'm not sure i understand how it should work, the `map.setCenter` i mean...can you provide a piece of code please?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my question and here is my code, in case anyone else will ever need something like that:
The cshtml drop-down:

```
        <select class="form-control" id="selectedValue" onchange="GoToLocation(this.value)">
            <option>Choose a station...</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListOfDropdown)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
```

The Controller:

```
        public JsonResult GetAllLocationById(int? id)
        {
            var data = _context.Stations.Where(m => m.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
            return Json(data);
        }
```

And the JavaScript function:

```
function GoToLocation(locationId) {
    $.get("/UserMap/GetAllLocationById?id=" + locationId,
        function (data, status) {
            if (data != null) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitudine, data.longitudine));
                map.setZoom(17);
            } else {
                map.setZoom(13);
                map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(46.770920, 23.589920));
            }
        }
    )
}
```

NOTE: if the `data` is null, i let him zoom-out the map, because that's what i wanted to do if choosing `Choose a station` from the drop-down, which was coming as null.